# Complex matrix derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

Let $\mathbf{V}\in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$ be an Hermitian and positive definite matrix. Let $\mathrm{vec(\mathbf{V})} \in \mathbb{C}^{N^2}$ be the classical vectorization operator. Let $|\mathbf{V}|$ be the determinant of $\mathbf{V}$. How can I evaluate the following complex derivative?
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial|\mathbf{V}|^{1/N}}{\partial\mathrm{vec(\mathbf{V})}^T}
\end{equation}

Thanks!

Comment: If $\def\p{\partial}\phi\;\,{\rm is\;real,\;{then}}\;\; V^*\!=\!V^T\;\implies\;\large\frac{\p\phi}{\p V^*}=\left(\frac{\p\phi}{\p V}\right)^T\,$ so in this case the two Wirtinger gradients are not independent, but simply transposes of each other. Therefore the gradient that Ben calculates below is the only possible gradient.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a derivative with respect to $\operatorname{vec}(V)^T$ will just give us a rearranged version of the derivative with respect to $V$.

For the derivative with respect to $V$, we could use the chain rule along with the [matrix calculus result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities)
$$
\frac{\partial |V|}{\partial V} = \operatorname{adj}(V) = |V|\cdot V^{-1},
$$
where adj denotes the adjugate matrix.  From there, 
$$
\frac{\partial |V|^{1/N}}{\partial V} = 
\frac 1N \cdot |V|^{(1-N)/N} \cdot \frac{\partial |V|}{\partial V} = 
\frac{|V|^{1/N}}{N}\cdot V^{-1}.
$$
It now suffices to rearrange the entries of this matrix, according to however the derivative of a function with respect to a row-vector is meant to be arranged.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is fine with me, but my concern was about the fact that $\mathbf{V}$ is a complex Hermitian matrix. I’m not sure about the need to use the “Wirtiger calculus” here..

Comment: Ah, I guess I missed the primary point of your question. My naive thought here is that because everything used is a complex-differentiable function (e.g. the derivative is a polynomial), the formula for the complex derivative should be the same as the formula of the real derivative.